# Beautifulsoup check span class and rel

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to check span class (glyphicon icon icon-positive = True) and if so take the value from tr rel (/reestr/clients/233/members/3567150). How i can do this?
I don't understand how to access this data.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://reestr.nostroy.ru/reestr?m.fulldescription=&m.shortdescription=&m.inn=6674374250&m.ogrnip=&bms.id=&bmt.id=&u.registrationnumber='
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
news = []
new_news = []
news = soup.findAll('table', class_='items table table-selectable-row table-striped')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
news = soup.find('table', class_='items table table-selectable-row table-striped')

for tr in news.find_all('tr'):
    if tr.find('span',class_='glyphicon icon icon-positive'):
        print(tr['rel'])
```

Note I changed the way you find `news` (with `.find` instead of `.find_all`) as there is only one object matching that condition.